# VIM: How to delete 3 words from the end of line in normal mode?

Tags: vim

What is the shortest combo?

P.S. I usually do <kbd>A</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+w</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+w</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+w</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>.
In other words, I have to jump into Insert mode.

P.P.S. <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> doesn't work.

Comment: Macro for removing N words?

Comment: if you are at the position you want to delete, just use `d$` to delete everything to the end of the line.

Comment: Usually I'm in the beginning of line

Comment: This question is a nice example of how almost everything in Vim is contextual. There are many ways to do what we want and the proper way may differ from one situation to the other. The same logic could be applied to "should I use a macro or should I use `n.` or should I use `:g`?" as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This sequence of commands,

```
$3bD
```

is the shortest way to do it I can think of at the moment but it leaves out an ugly trailing space.

```
$3gelD
```

is another way that gets rid of the trailing space.

You can also think outside the box and play with spaces instead of words:

```
$3F D
```

Comment: The last one may not be the same as it may be closer to using WORD boundaries instead of word boundaries (which `ge` & `b` use).

Comment: It fixes the trailing whitespace issue, though.

Comment: @romainl `$3F D` won't work if the words are separated by tabs or multiple spaces. `$3bDx` is slightly better but your other suggestion of `$3gelD` is probably best. `$3b3daw` does the same but is longer; `$daw..` is an interesting alternative.

Comment: Without a specific use case we are left with assumptions. `$3F D` assumes that the words are separated by spaces. `$d3b`, `$3bD` and variants doe the same, based on the OP's unsuccessful attempt to use `d3b` and the assumption that he knows about `B`.

Comment: @NikitaKouevda, of my solutions, I agree that `$3gelD` is probably the best. I like your `$daw..` a lot more, though. Care to put it as an answer?

Answer (score 9):

<kbd>$</kbd> <kbd>3</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> which [translates](http://rc3.org/2012/05/12/the-grammar-of-vim/) to

- <kbd>$</kbd> to the end of a line
- <kbd>3</kbd> three of whatever is next
- <kbd>b</kbd> backward three [one without modifier] words
- <kbd>D</kbd>  delete the characters under the cursor until the end of the line

In addition, you can also use the [normal](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#:normal) command in ex mode to achieve the same

```
:norm! $3bD
```

Answer (score 4):

$3bD

Or

$3bDx

...if you also want to delete the trailing space.

Answer (score 4):

Go to the end of the line, go back 3 words, then delete to the end of the line: <kbd>$</kbd> <kbd>3</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd>

or

Go to the end of the line, delete back 3 words, then delete the extra character: <kbd>$</kbd> <kbd>3</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>x</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

As others have mentioned, `$3bD` is the shortest, and `$3bDx` will suffice to remove the remaining whitespace, assuming it's exactly one space or tab.

In order to account for all whitespace, `$3gelD` can be used. This option has the benefit of cleaning up properly in most cases, but it fails when a line contains exactly 3 words because the `3ge` motion jumps back to the previous line.

An alternative approach is based on `daw`. Since `3daw` acts forward, either `$daw..` or `$3b3daw` must be used. For 3 words, `$daw..` is shorter and probably more desirable, but `$3b3daw` is more Vim-esque and can easily be extended to more words.

`b`, `ge`, and `w` can be replaced with `B`, `gE`, and `W` in order to remove WORDs instead of words.

Comment: Unfortunately, `$daw..` only works if you are not using the `virtualedit` option. With virtualedit to `all` or `onemore`, the alternative is `$caw<esc>..`.

Comment: Interesting; in that case, `$3bDx` would also fail.